# Why is Blender rendering QT animation weirdly?

Tags: rendering, animation

Recently blender has started to render my animations incorrectly (see image below)

Im using transparent background, using RGBA quicktime Mpge4.

Blender never did this before. Has Anyone go any idea whats going on?

FYI - Single frame transparent PNGs render correctly.

thanks

[image: Settings]

[image: This is meant to be a 3d model of a face]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try using another codecs, such as mp4/VP9 or QuickTime/HuffYUY

Comment: Hi Crantisz - Ill give it a go.

Comment: So, the only codec that allows RGBA transparency is the Quicktime container on the mac - HuffYUY kind of worked, but you can only see it in blender - so not much use - you can't convert the HuffYuy on Mac either -I  tried adobe media encoder, aftereffects, and nothing will open the file.